# Extracted application.properties and logback.xml outside the jar file, logs are not generated

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I am using logback in my spring boot application.

Until now I was using application.properties and logback.xml from within the classpath (inside the jar).

Now when I have extracted both the files in a config directory outside the jar, Logback is not working as expected.

Now I have used @PropertySource in the application to give the filepath of the application.properties and that is working as expected.

But when the property

```
logging.config=file:config/logback.xml
```

In the application.property is not working due to some reasons I guess.

Also when I try to give the path of logback with System.property is the code, it is working. So why am I not being able to solve this with application.properties.

Also I have ensured that there are no logback files inside the jar.

Comment: When exactly happens when putting it outside the JAR?

Comment: @dan1stiscrying, it is basically not creating any log file

Comment: Where is the config located? In your file system root? If you want it to be relative to your project instead of your file system root, try `logging.config=file:config/logback.xml`. or `logging.config=file:./config/logback.xml`

Comment: If the `config` directory is in the same place (next to) the jar file you created Spring Boot will automatically pickup the `application.properties`. No need for an `@PropertySource` (which probably won't work either as that will be loaded later then the one from Spring and logging is configured very early in the bootstrapping process). If you placed the configuration **not** in a config directory next to the jar but somewhere on the filesystem, add `--spring.config.additional-location=<path to config directory>` when starting to add it and let Spring Boot pickup the `application.properties`.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying, the config directory and the jar are both in the same directory. I tried doing both but still it continues the same behavior

Comment: @M.Deinum, the config directory and the jar are both in the same directory. 
So what should I do in this case, can I give the path of logback from the application.properties in the config directory or will I have to use the code method of System.setProperty("logging.config", "file:config/logback.xml"); only

Comment: Does it work with `System.setProperty`?

Comment: What you are passing as system property is a different path then what you pass in your `application.properties`. `file:config/logback.xml` and `file:/config/logback.xml` aren't the same paths.

Comment: Yes @dan1stiscrying is working with System.setProperty, but want to identify what is the issue for it to be working with application.properties.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I tried with both `file:config/logback.xml`, `file:/config/logback.xml`
and none if it is working in application.properties

Comment: I think the problem is that Spring needs to start logging before loading other things. Does it work when specifying it in the `application.properties` in your resources directory/classpath?

Comment: @dan1stiscrying, yes it works well when specified from inside the classpath

Comment: Yeah I think the `application.properties` in the `config` directory is loaded after logging has already occured so the logging config might be fixed at that point.